# Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade to 14.04 (Word Press Broken)

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, mysql

I'm hosting Wordpress on Ubuntu 12.04! The time has come to upgrade the OS to 14.04 and upwards!

During the installation noticed mysql was having few issues stopping. So i had to stop this manually.

After the upgrade had been completed, I had restarted the server to now find that I'm no longer able to access the website or get onto the WP-Admin.php page?

Has anyone else come across this? I had kept the default configs in place during the installation...

Also noticed that my putty session hangs during login. (after I've entered my password) and does nothing??

Any help would be greatful

Thanks

Comment: think about upgrade to 16.04 or 18.04, 12.04 was EOL since april 2017 and 14.04 will be EOL in april next year; you can try a  `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: How can i jump from 12.04 to 16.04?

Comment: personally, I upgrade all time my Ubuntu with bootable USB, but you can also do your upgrade like you do, 12.04 -> 14.04 -> 16.04 and after 18.04 (advantage of the USB device because of time save, you have the option "upgrade from 12.04 to --.04)

Comment: Ill give offline upgrade a go as last resort! In the mean time im getting this error: Installing new version of config file /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server any ideas?

Comment: it's not the error, we don't know what doesn't go right

Comment: Sorry i was meant to say that during OS Upgrade to 14.04 the installation gets stuck at the following: Installing new version of config file /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server and does nothing.